# She played / replayed the song repeatedly

Tags: sentence-choice

Which one is correct ?

> 1. She played the song repeatedly.
> 2. She replayed the song repeatedly.

Since the adverb repeatedly adds a meaning that something is done over and over again, should we  use the verb play  or this kinds of adverbs cause to use re-type verbs already for the sake of verb-adverb agreement?

Comment: Interesting! I was about to post a similar question!

Comment: Replayed repeatedly is redundant.

Comment: You might want to post these types of questions to http://writers.stackexchange.com.  There are broader issues to be discussed beyond English grammar.  Issues that might get a more full treatment on the other site.

Comment: @CoolHandLouis Thank you for your suggest.I think it will be useful.

Answer (score 5):

In general, I'd use "played" here.

If she played the song at least once *before the occasion you're describing here*, then "replayed" would be appropriate - but "played" would still also be appropriate.  Let's look at four examples:

- Version 1: "She put on her new CD, and played the first song.  I hated it immediately.  She noticed this, and played it to torture me." - This is weird.  Did she play it once, or twice?  Is the second "played" the same instance as the first?
- Version 2: "She put on her new CD, and played the first song.  I hated it immediately.  She noticed this, and replayed it to torture me." - This is reasonable!  She played the song twice.  The first time ("played") was just to hear it, and the second time ("replayed") was to torture me.
- Version 3: "She put on her new CD, and played the first song.  I hated it immediately.  She noticed this, and played it repeatedly to torture me." - This is also reasonable!  In this case the "repeatedly" essentially gives us a "set" of playings - that is, "played it repeatedly" means she played it some large number of times.  You *could* argue that it's ambiguous as to whether that first playing (from the first sentence) is part of that "large number of times", but that doesn't *matter* - the sentence is understood either way.
- Version 4: "She put on her new CD, and played the first song.  I hated it immediately.  She noticed this, and replayed repeatedly it to torture me." - This still works; it's much the same as Version 2.  The only difference is that the second "instance" of playing involved playing the song *several times*: she played it once, and *then* she played it multiple times.

Again, this only works because we kind of have two separate acts of "playing" - the one in the first sentence, and the one in the last sentence.  If we didn't have that first sentence, then yeah, "replayed repeatedly" would be redundant:

"She bought a CD with that song I hated on it.  She knew I hated it, and played it repeatedly to torture me."  We don't use "replayed" here because there's no earlier instance to repeat.

Comment: Ack!  You're right.  I'll correct those.

Answer (score 1):

The answer might be, "neither".  Another consideration is whether it's fundamentally the best way to describe this action.  There are subtle connotations to consider between 'repeatedly', 'over and over [again]', and 'again and again'.

See [google ngram: `the same song over and,the same song repeatedly,the same song again and`](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+same+song+over+and%2Cthe+same+song+repeatedly%2Cthe+same+song+again+and&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20same%20song%20over%20and%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20same%20song%20repeatedly%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20same%20song%20again%20and%3B%2Cc0)
[image]

The word 'repeatedly' is more curt, factual, and cold.  While 'repeatedly' might be found in a physician's notes, 'over and over' (or some variant) is understood viscerally (through feeling) since it is a repetition itself.

In this case, be sure you actually want to use 'repeatedly' for it's connotations. Since it bucks the trend of using "over and over" it's a little jarring in it's clinical precision, especially in the context of playing of a song.